# PostgreSQL 9.3 on Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I just got a VPS on DigitalOcean and put Ubuntu 13.10 on it. I'm trying to setup PostgreSQL for my Rails app. I inserted `deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main` in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list, then I tried with `deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ saucy-pgdg main` and `deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ lucid-pgdg main` (obviously ran `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`) but I keep getting this message when running `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3 pgadmin3`:

```
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-9.3 : Depends: postgresql-client-9.3 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The problem is that even if I try apt-getting postgresql-client-9.3 it tells me I need another package:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-client-9.3 : Depends: libpq5 (>= 9.3.2) but 9.1.11-0ubuntu0.13.10 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And after that, it keeps telling me to install libpq5, which it will not let me install.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be moved to askubuntu.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this does not really answer your question but I would re-install Ubuntu with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and you will have zero issues to install Postgresql 9.3. Rule of thumb is: if you get stuck with installation tasks you are asking for way more trouble when in production.

Just my oppinion but followed this advice with everything I install. Running dozens of clustered postgresql servers myself.

Comment: Yes this is stupid. Way too much of a hassle..

Comment: Nah, not stupid but hassle for sure. Can you vote my answer?:)